# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: not loading some resources

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and Spring MVC.

I have been dealing with the following problem: some resources (css or images) don't get loaded by my webpage while other do. They are in the same path and folder, the syntax is the same (i have checked by just switching the name of the resource and it worked).

For example, my Thymeleaf Template can find and read my own css files, but it won't read the bootstrap-4 one.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

And here an example of the code trying to read bootstrap.css:
[image]

The same problem happens with images of the same format.

Any ideas of what could be causing the issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't post code (the thymeleaf template) as images. Those become unreadable.

Comment: Did you configure any resourceHandlers by implementing WebMvcConfigurer? If then post resource configuration as well. I guess there must be hardcoding files paths configured.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50196388/600135

Comment: Are you using spring security in this same project ?

Comment: I am not using spring security within the project.

I haven't used any resourceHandler, when should they be used? Doesn't Spring scan the resources folder anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a resource handler by extending a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Something like this.

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Anyway, the css files should be in the `css` directory

Comment: I am not sure what a resourceHandler does or is (i will explore that), anyhow i tried this code but the result is the same. Also, I have updated the folder name to css as you suggested

Comment: Place the css files in the path `/main/webapp/css`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I understood what the problem was: intelliJ.
It didn't see the new files added to the project.

Running *mvn clean install* fixed the problem